# Bootstrap Thumbnail issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my caption be inside thumbnail , and that image won't overflow over the caption :

My html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="1.8s">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <a href="http://stoptheworld-iwannagetoff.com/"> <img src="images/stoptheworldxxx.jpg"></a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="http://loll.com/" ><p class="caption text-center">Thumbnail image</p></a>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
           width:100%;
           overflow: hidden;


}

img{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;

}

img:hover{
    transform:scale(1.3);opacity:0.6;background-color: blue;

}
```

I tried putting caption above the div tag that closing the thumbnail, but then the image overflows over the caption.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="1.8s">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="http://stoptheworld-iwannagetoff.com/"> <img src="images/stoptheworldxxx.jpg"></a>
          <div class="caption text-center">
           <a href="http://loll.com/" >Thumbnail image</a>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>`